# What is the best way to monitor a program performance cross platform

Tags: windows, cross-platform

I know in linux you can use ps or top command to capture the performance of a certain program you are running. But is there any equivalent way to capture info in windows.

The goal is to have a way to run the script/program(of any language) that can start a program and monitor the performance of it. CROSS-PLATFORM is the main issue.

Comment: Windows Task Manager show performances of your running apps.

Comment: And side note: collecting information about CPU usage tells you **nothing** about the performance of an application. It tells you how much CPU is used; nothing else. If an application consumes 100% cpu ... that could be because it is doing a lot of work; or because it is going berserk; for example by filling up your disk with log files; only stopped by running out of disk space after many hours (happened lately to us). So, if you are interested in **performance**; you need to look at different tools/metrics.

Comment: I don't understand, what does your question have to do with the tags `java` and `c++`?  Executables are language independent.  Try adding a tag for "performance" or "monitoring".

Comment: Are you planning on using libraries in Java or C++ to access the performance information?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, that is a good point. I was trying to monitor the program written in those two languages. But you are right. It has nothing to do with it. I was thinking it will be best it can capture with the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows machine tasklist can be more useful. For using the tasklist you can take help using tasklist /?

For memory and cpu time to capture , you can use something like:

```
c:\>tasklist /v
```

This will list the PID, mem usage, cpu time.

```
Examples:
TASKLIST
TASKLIST /M
TASKLIST /V /FO CSV
TASKLIST /SVC /FO LIST
TASKLIST /M wbem*
TASKLIST /S system /FO LIST
TASKLIST /S system /U domain\username /FO CSV /NH
TASKLIST /S system /U username /P password /FO TABLE /NH
TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME ne NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /FI "STATUS eq running"
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: THAT is what I am looking for. Thanks so much.